# WRT compiling source code on a Mac, what is ldd?

Tags: macos, debugging, compiler-construction, v8, ldd

I'm trouble shooting a broken PyV8 install and noticed discussion on an online forum about using `ldd`, a command / program I've never seen before.

What is it and where do I get it?

Here is the discussion I discovered it in: http://groups.google.com/group/pyv8/browse_thread/thread/c14330fe431a69a7?pli=1

Comment: Refer to http://schumakov.info/howto-osx.php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One user of the discussion shows an ldd dump in a debian vm. ldd is a linux tool to check which libraries a dynamically linked binary is linked to. OSX however, doesn't have ldd. The osx equivalent is called otool -L. You need to install xcode in order to get it.